# Redirect to a rails path using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

how do I refresh a rails path with an error message using ajax. I'm waiting for a callback from a payment API and if I get an error I want to reload the page and show the error. Problem is I'm using ajax. How can I pull this off ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refreshing the page to display a simple feedback error is completely unnecessary and long-winded. A much cleaner, and more direct method, is to use js to update the dom within the callback.

A very very simple demonstration:

```
$(".errors").append('<li>My error</li>');
```

In the name of simplicity, do that (or something similar within javascript), don't redirect just to display an error.

Comment: yeah this is the best possible answer!

Comment: @AlainGoldman create another question if you have trouble implementing this properly.

Answer (score 1):

If error is persisted on database, you can use [window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) on callback function in order to relaod the page with errors.

Answer (score 1):

In the action that responds to the AJAX request you can do

```
flash[:alert] = "My error"
```

And then have the action render the redirect as such:

```
render js: "window.location.href = '#{my_named_route_path}'"
```

Or, you may want to write a method to abstract this, such as:

```
app/controllers/application_controller.rb

def redirect_to_via_xhr_if_applicable(url, options = {})
  flash[:info] = options[:info] if options.key?(:info)
  flash[:alert] = options[:alert] if options.key?(:alert)
  flash[:notice] = options[:notice] if options.key?(:notice)
  if request.xhr?
    render js: "window.location.href = '#{url}'"
  else
    redirect_to(url)
  end
end
```

Then you can just make this call from your AJAX (or non-AJAX) action:

```
redirect_to_via_xhr_if_applicable(my_named_route_path, alert: 'My error!')
```